# My app refuses to execute code if an IF statement is present

Tags: vb.net

```
If Client.DownloadString("https://www.imdb.com/title/" & ID).Contains(">Episode Guide<") Then
    If ImdbURL.Equals(textvalue + " movie") Then
        result = String.Empty
        Return result.ToString()
        Exit Function
    End If

    ImdbURL = getIMDbUrl(textvalue + " movie")
Else
    ID = ImdbURL.Replace("https://www.imdb.com/title/", "")
    ID = ID.Replace("/", "")
End If
```

So this is the code that does not work. The client.downloadstring runs perfectly fine outside the .contains environment (tested as defined string) but if I try to do .contains the client.downloadstring does not throw an error but ignores itself as if it were a comment and not a valid line. Idk why. To me this is mind-blowingly illogical.

Comment: "Ignores itself"...makes no sense, as you've clearly realised. It's impossible that the `if` code would actually not be executed. Surely it's more likely that the call to `.Contains()` is simply returning a value different from the one you expected? What _actually_ happens when you step through this code line by line? What values do you see? What path does the code take? What path did you _expect_ it to take? I suspect the actual issue here is that you haven't debugged it to find out what _is_ happening.

Comment: In your sample code, you return an empty string as "result" is set to Empty. I don't know what you are trying to do here but I think you might want to put DownloadString in a variable before using it in the If statement.

Comment: I have checked the value of the source code of the website i download as i stored it as TEXT file. Even when i store it as text file and try to read a specific line (in this case 1239) the line returns as empty even though the .contains should be positive. If i exclude .contains it gets defined properly.

Comment: None of that information properly answers the specific question I posed to you about what **exactly** the code does and what **exactly** you expected instead. But anyway, Client.DownloadString does not store the data in a file, it returns a string. You are then passing that string directly to .Contains() without storing it anywhere else. .Contains() returns true or false depending on whether it finds that string within the downloaded text or not. And then that true/false is then given to the `If` statement to evaluate. The original downloaded string is not preserved.

Comment: As the_lotus says, if you want to re-use the downloaded data you need to put it into a separate string variable first, and then run the .Contains() function on that string instead. That way you can use the same value later on for another purpose. But where are you trying to read a specific line anyway?? That's not in what you showed us, so it's confusing to us when you talk about code which isn't in your example - don't forget we can't see the rest of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first store the downloaded content into a string.

```
Dim content As String = Client.DownloadString("https://www.imdb.com/title/" & ID)
```

Now, after downloading, you have to check that `content` is set to something.

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(content) Then
    ' Signal an error.
Else
    ' Success!
    ' Process content.
End If
```

Now, in the `Else` case, you can do the processing you want, which is not completely clear from the code that you posted.

Comment: As i said, i did store it in a string. It works. But as soon as i include it in the .contains it returns no value when i debug (the string value, as you stated, literally does not execute at all). I run it in virtualbox on linux but it should be working fine in virtualbox.

Comment: @falldses "(the string value, as you stated, literally does not execute at all makes no sense at all. string value doesn't execute.

Comment: @falldses - Not sure what you mean by _... it returns no value...._ `Contains()` returns either `True` or `False`. If you still need help, let me know, I will be glad to help you out

Answer (score -1):

Thanks folks for help. Apparently if you use IF twice where you should use IF and ELSEIF can potentially break the code and the whole .NET. Idk if thats due to me running it in Virtualbox or whatever but when i added a single elseif instead of an if statement it ran perfectly fine. Makes no sense. If someone wants to report it to big micro be my guest!

Comment: What exactly do you think needs reporting?

Comment: If
End If
If 
End If was changed to If ElseIf End If. 
this fixed the issue. It is illogical.

Comment: No, a nested If will only execute if the containing If is true and the nested If is also true. An ElseIf only executes if the initial If is False and the ElseIf is True. Perfactly logical.

Comment: it was not nested.

Comment: It was nested. Look at your posted code. An If statement inside another If...End If is nested.